# RabbitMQ: does unbinding queues from exchanges affect client connections

Tags: rabbitmq

Does unbinding a queue from an exchange in RabbitMQ affects in any way connections of consumers to that queue?

I want to unbind a queue from an exchange without messages in that queue being lost or connection to the consumer being disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

Binding/Unbinding queues from exchanges doesn't affect connections, channels and consumers in any way (apart that message flow may become different).

Side effect of unbinding queues is that it may become empty when all messages will be processed by consumers, and, depends on client library, consumers may raise exception due to receive timeout, but this is very edge case.